# A question on Homer normalization

Tags: ngs, normalization, homer

When using [annotatePeaks.pl script](http://homer.ucsd.edu/homer/ngs/quantification.html) from Homer software to create histograms, the output is normalized per bp per peak (on top of normalization to 10 million tags).

What does it mean to normalize per bp per peak?

---

[Hypergeometric Optimization of Motif EnRichment](http://homer.ucsd.edu/homer/) (HOMER v4.11, 10-24-2019), is used for *de novo* motif discovery and NGS analysis and written in Perl and C++.

[image]

Crossposted from [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/9514514/), as there is no reply on biostars.